# Using Windows account credentials for Web App account?

Tags: windows, node.js, authentication

My institute currently has a local domain running on Windows Server, like a lot of business networks. I would like to build a web app that users can log into using their Windows login credentials, so that they don't have to manage multiple usernames and passwords.

Is this possible?

The app would be built with node.js and designed so that it could launch on mobile devices that are not on the network.

Also, I'm a student so please forgive my overwhelming ignorance on the matter. :)

Comment: Since you're using a domain, you could probably integrate LDAP using NTLM. There's a good passport module for it [here](https://github.com/auth0/passport-windowsauth). Or if you want raw integration, [LDAPJS](http://ldapjs.org/).

Comment: Well this is a fun rabbit hole to explore. Thanks Ben! If you post this as an answer then I'd be more than happy to "up" it.